# How to convert this SQL Query to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with turning this SQL query into SQLAlchemy

`SELECT Recipe.id, Recipe.name, AVG(Rating.rating) AS ar FROM Recipe LEFT OUTER JOIN Rating ON Recipe.id = Rating.recipe_id GROUP BY Recipe.id ORDER BY Recipe.id ASC;`

I currently have:

`session.query(Recipe,func.avg(Rating.rating).label('average')).outerjoin(Rating).filter(Recipe.id == Rating.recipe_id).group_by(Recipe.id).all()`

but this returns something similar to this which is missing the elements that don't have any ratings:

```
 id |       name       |         ar
----+------------------+--------------------
  1 | First Response   | 4.0000000000000000
 34 | First Response 2 | 3.0000000000000000
```

While the PostgreSQL query in command line returns:

```
 id |       name       |         ar
----+------------------+--------------------
  1 | First Response   | 4.0000000000000000
 34 | First Response 2 | 3.0000000000000000
 35 | First Response 2 |
 36 | First Response 2 |
```

These are my models:

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    prep_time = Column(Integer)
    difficulty = Column(Integer)
    vegeterian = Column(Boolean)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    ratings = relationship("Rating")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Recipe(name='{}', prep_time='{}', difficulty='{}', vegeterian='{}', user='{}')>".format(
            self.name, self.prep_time, self.difficulty, self.vegeterian, self.user_id
        )

class Rating(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rating'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipe.id'))
    rating = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Rating(name='{}', rating='{}')>".format(self.recipe.name, self.rating)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
filter(Recipe.id == Rating.recipe_id)
```

because the outer join already produces the correct ON clause based on the foreign key relationship between the models. The filter expression is added to the WHERE clause and results in UNKNOWN for rows that have no rating, and so they are removed from the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I didn't realize this at the time. I really appreciate your quick response.